# Bokeh: Slider is not updating results on Hbar plot

Tags: widget, slider, bokeh

I wrote the following code for using a slider to filter and update values on a Hbar plot in Bokeh.
The plot (as shown in the picture) outputs correctly, but when I move the slider nothing happens.
I'd greatly appreciate any feedback.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, gridplot
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, save, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, DatetimeTickFormatter, FactorRange, DataTable, TableColumn, DateFormatter
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs, Slider
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xls=pd.ExcelFile(path)
test_data=pd.read_excel(xls, 'test_data')

display(test_data)

AREA    counts
A   500
B   100
C   70
D   50
E   40
F   20
G   10
H   2

def myplot(doc):

    source = ColumnDataSource(pd.DataFrame(data=test_data))
    area_list=source.data['AREA'].tolist()[::-1]

# Creating the Bar Chart

    p = figure(y_range=area_list ,plot_height=500, plot_width=500, title="Total counts per area",
           x_axis_label='counts', y_axis_label='AREA')
           

    p.hbar(y='AREA', right='counts',  height=1, 
            line_color="black", fill_color='red',line_width=1, 
            source=source)

    def update_plot(attr, old, new):

        Number_of_counts = slider.value
        new_data = test_data.loc[test_data['counts'] >=Number_of_counts]
        source = ColumnDataSource(data=new_data)


# Make a slider object: slider
    slider = Slider(start=1, end=100, step=1, value=1, title='counts')

# Attach the callback to the 'value' property of slider
    slider.on_change('value', update_plot)
 
    doc.add_root(column(slider, p))


show(myplot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the value of the `source` variable, but the old source is still there, being used by all the created models.

Instead of recreating the source, try to reassign the `data` attribute of the old source:

```
# source = ColumnDataSource(data=new_data)
source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(new_data)
```

Comment: Hi @Eugene Pakhomov. Thanks for replying. Would you mind sharing how can i do that reassignment?

Comment: thanks @Eugene Pakhomov. Now it works. Would you mind sharing documentation about '.data'. Also, if you don't mind me asking something additional to my original question: is there a way to uptake the y-axis based on the update 'source' (number of categories shown in the y-axis).  thanks again for your feedback.

Comment: On the former - https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#columndatasource plus the API documentation for `ColumnDataSource`. On the latter - you should be able to change `p.x_range.factors` dynamically.

Comment: Thanks @Eugene Pakhomov. I’ll look into the documentation you suggested